# How to solve the matrix equation $A\overrightarrow{x}=\overrightarrow{b}$ in Matlab when nullitity$(A)\neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab

Say,

$A= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 &1 \\ 
0 & 1  &1 \\ 
0 &0  &0 
\end{pmatrix}$ and $\overrightarrow{b}= \begin{pmatrix}
8 \\ 
-5  \\ 
0  
\end{pmatrix}$

and I want to solve the system $A\overrightarrow{x}=\overrightarrow{b}$. The solution is

$\overrightarrow{x}= \begin{pmatrix} 8\\ -5 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + k\begin{pmatrix} -1\\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$

How can I solve this kind of systems using Matlab?

The backslash function (x=A\b) of course doesn't work because nullity(A) isn't 0.

I can manage to solve this kind of problems using the Symbolic Toolbox (see below), but isn't there a Matlab built-in function (similar to the backslash) that can solve this directly?

---

> A=[1 0 0; 0 1 0; 1 1 0]'
>
> b=[8 -5 0]'
>
> x=sym('x',[3,1]);
>
> eqn= A*x==b;
>
> [XX(1,1),XX(2,1),XX(3,1),params,conds]=solve(eqn,x,'ReturnConditions',true);
>
> vv1=diff(XX,params(1));
>
> vv0=XX-params(1)*vv1;
>
> X=matlabFunction(XX)
>
> v0=eval(vv0)
>
> v1=eval(vv1)
>
> %the solution is x=v0+k*v1

Comment: What if you take away the last trivial row $0=0$? Alternatively try **pinv(A)*b** But you don't get all the solutions.

Comment: (The trivial row doesn't cause the "problem"). Thanks, pinv(A) is a good start.

Comment: Note though that pinv gives you solution even if there is no solution to the system, which means that it's up to you to test that $b$ belongs to the image of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

You should use MATLAB [`pinv()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pinv.html) function which solves Least Squares problem using the SVD.

This method is slower yet much more robust than using `\` (It always returns the least norm solution).

By itself it can handle problems with large condition number (Having eigen value which is zero -> Condition number which is infinite are included).
If you are dealing with edge cases (Really extreme condition number) you should use the `tol` parameter.
This parameter allows you to threshold small eigen values.